# In Tsql, how do i replace a value if the value is not null?

Tags: t-sql

For a directory, I want the words "visit website" to appear only if the member has entered a website. I do not want to retrieve the actual web site url.

Replace and Coalesce seem to work only if the value is null.

This is certainly not working

```
SELECT replace (eweb,'website','website') as value 
from Web_FacStaffdir 
where eweb is not null
```

Comment: The example you gave is not quite relevant. Please, settle `eweb` column example input and output you want to get as the result

Comment: I knew it was not relevant,  i just did not know where to start for some reason.  but if i don't put some code in, i am damned. and damned if i don't, i guess.  the answer below made me realize i needed think about evaluating the string, and i was thinking primarily of the is not null part.  which was only half of what i needed, and i already had that.  it's great to get feedback.  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(eweb) > 0 THEN 'website' ELSE '' END as value
from Web_FacStaffdir 
where eweb is not null
```

Comment: thanks bro!  I should ask questions more often!!  i cant answer for 5 more minutes.

Comment: No worries, SO is an awesome resource and can save hours - often better to search SO than Google ;o)

Comment: ah, thanks @buKanner i was not quite out of the woods. though this query worked alone, if i add it to the rest of the select i got the error 'subquery returned more than 1 value.  This is not permitted'  so if someone else needs this, this is what ended up working"  for me...                  `SELECT  [ID],[EID],[EName],[etitle],[email],[EXT],[Active],(select CASE WHEN LEN(eweb) > 0 THEN 'website'  ELSE '' END) as yesweb,[eweb] FROM [Web_FacStaff`